# PHP ftp_nlist give different strings

Tags: php, ftp

I've got a class, which should delete a folder on an FTP-Server.
The connection works well, deleting of a specific file also works.
Now, I want to delete the files in a loop.
My problem is:
On one FTP-Server, the files (fetched by nlist) looks like this:

```
array:3 [
  0 => "/var/www/clxpreview.ch/public_html/test-dgis/index.html"
  1 => "/var/www/clxpreview.ch/public_html/test-dgis/."
  2 => "/var/www/clxpreview.ch/public_html/test-dgis/.."
]
```

On the other (new installed) FTP-Server, it just looks like this:

```
array:3 [
  0 => "drwxr-xr-x    2 1001     1001         4096 Nov 11 11:53 ."
  1 => "drwxr-xr-x    4 1001     33           4096 Nov 11 11:51 .."
  2 => "-rw-r--r--    1 1001     1001         3231 Nov 11 11:51 index.html"
]
```

Same PHP-Code, same files, just an other server.

How can I configure the server, that it looks like the same on both servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the solution. I've been using `$subItems = $this->nlist('-ls ' . $path);` to fetch all items, but this returned the different results.
Now, I'm using `$subItems = $this->nlist($path);` and this is returning only the full path of the files, exactly what I want.